# JSON Transformation using JQ

Tags: json, iteration, transform, jq

I am trying to transform my JSON to different structure using JQ. I am able to partially achieve my new structure, however i get a additional blocks of data.

As i iterate i am able to get the structure in new format. But additional structures are coming.

Code Snippet- https://jqplay.org/s/3gulSlZiWz

JSON

```
    {
      "amazon": {
        "activeitem": 2,
        "createdDate": "2019-01-15T17:36:31.588Z",
        "lastModifiedDate": "2019-01-15T17:36:31.588Z",
        "user": "net",
        "userType": "new",
        "items": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "harry potter",
            "state": "sold",
            "type": {
              "branded": false,
              "description": "artwork",
              "contentLevel": "season"
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "adidas shoes",
            "state": "in inventory",
            "type": {
              "branded": false,
              "description": "Spprts",
              "contentLevel": "season"
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "watch",
            "state": "returned",
            "type": {
              "branded": false,
              "description": "walking",
              "contentLevel": "special"
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "adidas shoes",
            "state": "in inventory",
            "type": {
              "branded": false,
              "description": "running",
              "contentLevel": "winter"
            }
          }
        ],
        "product": {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "adidas shoes",
          "source": "dealer",
          "destination": "resident"
        }
      }
    }
```

JQ Query:

```
      .amazon| 
      {  
          userType: .userType,
          userName: .user,
          itemCatalog: {   
             itemId: .items[].id, 
             name: .items[].name  
          }
      }
```

Expected Response:

```
 {
    "userType": "new",
    "userName": "net",
    "itemCatalog": {
      "itemId": 1,
      "name": "harry potter"
    },{
      "itemId": 2,
      "name": "adidas shoes"
    }, {
      "itemId": 3,
      "name": "watch"
    },{
      "itemId": 4,
      "name": "adidas shoes"
    }
  }
```

But getting something weird long duplicated response.

Comment: Your "expected response" isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in a comment, the "expected response" is not JSON and probably not what you want anyway.  The following would make sense and in any case illustrates how to iterate appropriately:

```
.amazon
| { userType: .userType,
    userName: .user,
    itemCatalog: (.items | map({ itemId: .id, name} ))
  }
```

### Output

```
{
  "userType": "new",
  "userName": "net",
  "itemCatalog": [
    {
      "itemId": 1,
      "name": "harry potter"
    },
    {
      "itemId": 2,
      "name": "adidas shoes"
    },
    {
      "itemId": 3,
      "name": "watch"
    },
    {
      "itemId": 4,
      "name": "adidas shoes"
    }
  ]
}
```